# Software for tracking how popular a web site is

Tags: asp.net, web

Is there a (free!) software/components that I can use to track how my web site is being used - which pages are most popular, how many times was the site visitied today, yesterday etc...

Answer (score 6):

How about Google Analytics? http://google.com/analytics

Comment: Exactly what I came here to say.

Answer (score 0):

The information you want is (mostly) in the server logs, so I'd ask the server admin to give you access to some statistic-script (if it's installed).

Here's an open software for website analytics:
http://www.openwebanalytics.com/

And you can - of course - always give your data to Google and let them generate the statistics using "Google Analytics". It requires including a piece of code into your website.

Answer (score 0):

AWStats is a good option, but +1 for Google Analytics.